# Слова "бандит" и "гангстер"

Tags: значение-слов, синонимы, заимствования

Можно ли употребить в тексте слово "гангстер" вместо слова "бандит" и наоборот? Есть ли тут условности? Слова вроде синонимичные (банда-"ганг" - отсюда и бандит, гангстер).  Но можно ли их ставить в тексте при обозначении одного и того же человека?

Answer (score 1):

> ГАНГСТЕР [тэ], -а; м. [англ. gangster] В США и некоторых других
>   странах: участник организованной группы преступников; бандит. /
>   Бранно. Тот, кто повинен в каких-л. преступлениях; преступник. Для
>   тебя нет ничего святого, ты просто г.! Гангстеры пера (о беспринципных
>   и продажных писаках). <Гангстерский (см.).

То есть в узком смысле слова несколько отличаются областью применения, в широком - почти совпадают. В таких случаях выбор надо делать в зависимости от требований стилистики текста.

> Но можно ли их ставить в тексте при обозначении одного и того же
>   человека?

Но это-то уж совсем непонятно. В зачем?! Чтобы не повторяться? Не думаю, что оправдано.

Насчет "мафиозо". Его нет в словарях. Есть "мафиози". Ко всему прочему, "мафиози" не равнозначен бандиту или гангстеру и не замыкается на Италии вообще, не только на Сицилии.

Comment: *Насчет "мафиозо". Его нет в словарях.*  - не совсем так. Его иногда включают в словари (даже Лопатин не побрезговал), но это далеко не толковые словари и даже не орфоэпические.

Answer (score 0):

Без контекста тут сказать невозможно, эти слова не эквивалентны. "Гангстер" - это всегда американский бандит, в отношении русского бандита это слово будет выглядеть странновато. "Бандит" - это общее слово, я бы сказал, интернациональное, но всё же оно имеет более русский оттенок. Ну и вообще нужно учитывать национальную специфику, например, говоря о сицилийце, правильнее сказать "мафиозо".

Comment: В русском языке нет слова "мафиозо".

Comment: @behemothus, вы так полагаете? Даже не собираюсь спорить на эту тему, считайте как вам угодно.

Comment: Если не собираетесь спорить - просто исправьте. Я, собственно, тоже спорить не собираюсь.

Comment: @behemothus, я бы исправил, если бы это не было вашим личным, ничем не подкрепленным мнением. В русском языке такое слово есть, и оно активно употребляется. Оно даже в словарях есть, если вы не поленитесь глянуть. Да, оно заимствованное и имеет очень узкое значение, но это не значит, что его нет в языке.

Comment: Я надеюсь, вы-то не поленитесь указать нормативный словарь, чтобы подтвердить свое "неличное" мнение?! (+++) Вообще-то посылать других в словари искать то, что ВЫ доказываете, считается неприличным...

Comment: @behemothus, знаете, читаю я ваши заявления, и сразу вспоминается детская песенка "ж..а есть, а слова нет". Так и тут - вроде вот оно слово, и даже широко используется, а оказывается нет его, и точка. Ситуация...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99436/discussion-between-behemothus-and-freim).

Comment: Господа, снизим градус дискуссии. @behemothus, freim

Comment: Ну коли так... Я вообще не намерен вступать в дискуссии. До обнародования ссылки на словарь - точно, это противоречит мои представлениям о научной порядочности. А с "жопой" - прошу сюда: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/456170

Answer (score 0):

Слову "бандит" присуща более сильная эмоциональная окраска, и оно может использоваться с целью делегитимизации одной из сторон в военном противоборстве. Чтобы было понятнее, приведу исторический пример.

Во время Контртеррористической Операции в Чечне российские СМИ называли членов вооружённых формирований боевиками. Не скажу, что этот термин совсем нейтрален, но он не нацелен на то, чтобы выпятить негативную коннотацию.

В то же время, комментаторы и блогеры, стоявшие на стороне федералов, часто и сознательно предпочитали термин "бандиты".  Некоторые из военных также использовали в интервью именно этот термин.