# Про какое слово можно сказать что оно ЕСТЬ в языке?

Tags: выбор-слов

В ходе обсуждения одного вопроса (не хотелось бы сейчас давать ссылку) возник вопрос о понимании выражения "такого слова нет в языке". Понятно, что само по себе выражение разговорное, в строгом тексте автор бы написал что-то типа "это слово не зафиксировано такими-то и такими-то источниками". Но вот какими именно источниками должно фиксироваться слово для пополнения собой общеязыкового словарного запаса?!

Дополнительной путаницы вносит мнение Владимира  Пахомова.

> 87. Не верьте расхожей фразе «Жопа есть, а слова такого нет». Слово жопа есть в словарях русского языка. Кстати, ученые предполагают, что
>       оно восходит к древнему индоевропейскому корню со значением «впадина,
>       яма» и родственно слову дупло.

https://meduza.io/feature/2019/09/30/govorit-prisazhivaytes-vmesto-sadites-nevezhlivo-zvonit-kogda-nibud-stanet-normoy-polmandarina-pishetsya-slitno

Нисколько не опровергая фактическую часть этого тезиса, хочется спросить, а о каких словарях-то речь? В какие именно словари должна была попасть "жопа", чтобы маститый лингвист признал её право на существование? Ведь есть куча словарей разного толка - от диалектных словарей и даже "личных" словарей одного автора до словарей табуированной лексики и сленга.

***Итак, можно ли вне контекста понять, что означает выражение "этого слова нет в языке"? И если да, то как именно это надо понимать?***

Вопрос не праздный, ибо, как я убедился, может породить бесконечные и бессодержательные споры.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос, как Вы любите говорить, чисто терминологический. Смотря что понимать под термином ЯЗЫК. Современный русский язык - это "*национальный язык великого русского народа, форма русской национальной культуры*" по М. Фоминой. Это вся совокупность языковых средств, в том числе и говоры и наречия, а также социальные жаргоны. Высшая форма национального языка - русский литературный язык, это понятие постоянно меняется. *Современный русский литературный язык* - язык нормированный, обслуживающий культурные потребности народа - язык государственных актов, науки, печати, радио, театра, художественной литературы. **Состав словаря там регламентирован, подчинён общепринятому образцу.** Вот он противопоставлен диалектам и жаргонам. Чтобы слово вошло в этот язык, оно должно стать **общеупотребительным**, тогда оно войдёт и в общий словарь. А пока указанное Вами слово употребляется далеко не всеми, чаще говорят "ягодицы" (у Ожегова - "Задняя мясистая часть тела человека") или укороченное "зад"; есть много эвфемизмов: "нижняя часть тела", "таз" как остаток термина "тазовые кости", разговорные "попа", "булки", "корма" и т.д. Видимо, люди избегают этого слова, чтобы не показаться некультурными, поэтому в языке *как высшей форме национального языка* его нет.

Comment: Людмила, спасибо, конечно, но, во-первых, я совсем не это называю "терминологическими вопросами", а во-вторых, я оговорился, что есть куча разных словарей  - соответственно и "языков" может быть много. Вопрос именно в том, какой язык подразумевается в обычном выражении "слова нет в языке".

Comment: *"национальный язык великого русского народа"* - как только в научное определение добавляется слово "великий", оно превращается в мантру для слепоглупонемогпупых. Не находите? Вот это действительно вопрос терминологический. Украинский язык - язык великого украинского народа, амхарский языык - язык великого эфиопского народа, кхмерский язык -  язык великого камбоджийского народа... Вот это уже терминологичесий вопрос, да.  Интерсно бы  узнать, что Зализняк сказал бы на этот счет. Он всегда любил пройтись по подобным авторам.

Comment: Людмила, я бы с удовольствием продолжил разговор, но во избежание вандализма в комментариях, пожалуй, закрою тему. Через неделю-две, возможно, продолжим.... Ах, черт... не могу... раньше свойц вопрос можно было закрыть в любое время... Ну тогда придется терпеть. Извините.